# Sharing sound resource with service

Tags: android, service, audio

I have some activities and one service. I want to share a sound resource file (in the activities' res/raw folder primarily, but possibly in assets/) with the service. The activities and the service are in different APKs, signed with different keys.

One way is to read the file into memory, but I'd like to avoid that.

Is there perhaps an option of sharing "file handles" with a service?

Any pointers for how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance, 
 Jonas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went with `ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor()` on the service in the end. Should be possible to send an `AssetFileDescriptor` over IPC but didn't manage to.